# ISO Mounting Software for a Windows VM

Tags: windows-server-2003, virtual-machines, iso

I have read and viewed this [question on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/2327/best-free-iso-mounting-software-for-wind) and NONE of these options work on a Parallels VM running 64 bit windows server 2003. Does anyone know of any ISO mounting Software that will work on a VM, or how I need to change Parallels to get it working?

@Rajat was kind enough to mention PowerISO and while the device drivers fail, it will still start up and allow me to extract the Image!!

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't mount the ISO directly as a VM optical drive ( as per http://download.parallels.com/desktop/v6/docs/en/Parallels_Desktop_Users_Guide/23249.htm )

Comment: I dont have the access to install unless you are the "root node" which I am not, so basically it is an access issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to mount from the guest, then I would recommend Virtual CloneDirve.  It works with server 2008.

*Virtual CloneDrive works and behaves just like a physical CD/DVD drive, however it exists only virtually.*

http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html

Comment: Like I said it doesn't work on server 2003 64 bit

Comment: I have installed Virtual CloneDrive on many systems (both 32 and 64bit) and never had an issue. Can you expand on how it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You're sure that [MagicDisc](http://www.magiciso.com/tutorials/miso-magicdisc-history.htm) doesn't work? I've used it in virtual machines running under ESXi 3.5 and 4, XenServer 5, VMware Player, and VirtualPC. What does Parallels VM have to do with it? You're installing it on the VM guest, right?

Comment: PowerISO is work for the same

Comment: I sure magicDisc doesn't work it just throws a driver error on start up. Parallels is the VM that I am using, I just thought that info might be useful information. Lots of VMs have the ability to mount there own ISO's without any installation, I don't think Parallels is one of them, but I thought someone might be able to confirm that. I am not sure about the installation as It is a managed hosting company's VPS. :)

Comment: I'm still confused. Are you trying to mount an ISO from the guest or the host?

Comment: @Rajat PowerISO works! the install fails but it will still start up and allow me to extract the Image!!